# challenges with .net generics and AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, generics, automapper, viewmodel

I have an interface below

```
public interface IEntity<T>
{
     T Id { get; set; }
    DateTime Created { get; set; }
    DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    [Timestamp] byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

}
```

This interface was implemented by a class

```
  public partial class UrlRec: IEntity<Int64>
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; } 
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
   [Timestamp] public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

I created a ViewModel for the class UrlRecModel. How do I write a generic extension method to the ViewModel to the class and vice versal using AutoMapper.

here is my viewmodel

```
 public partial class UrlRecordModel : BaseIbileHubEntityModel
{
    #region Properties

    [IbileHubResourceDisplayName("Admin.System.SeNames.Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [IbileHubResourceDisplayName("Admin.System.SeNames.EntityId")]
    public int EntityId { get; set; }

    [IbileHubResourceDisplayName("Admin.System.SeNames.EntityName")]
    public string EntityName { get; set; }

    [IbileHubResourceDisplayName("Admin.System.SeNames.IsActive")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [IbileHubResourceDisplayName("Admin.System.SeNames.Language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [IbileHubResourceDisplayName("Admin.System.SeNames.Details")]
    public string DetailsUrl { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I believe it's no logical to say "an interface was inherited by a class". A class can only 'implement' an interface not extend it. Just a quick suggestion.

Comment: thank you for the correction

Comment: How does you ViewModel class look? What is the problem with  AutoMapper you are having?

Comment: i edited to show the viewmodel. can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

I have created these two extension methods.

```
 public static IEntity<T> ToModel<T>(this IEntityViewModel<T> viewModel)
    {
        return (IEntity<T>)Mapper.Map(viewModel, viewModel.GetType(), typeof(IEntity<T>));
    }

    public static IEntityViewModel<T> ToViewModel<T>(this IEntity<T> entity)
    {
        return (IEntityViewModel<T>)Mapper.Map(entity, entity.GetType(), typeof(IEntityViewModel<T>));
    }
```

and i have used it here.

```
IEntityViewModel<Int64> entityViewModel = urlRec.ToViewModel<Int64>();
        IEntity<Int64> entity = entityViewModel.ToModel<Int64>();
```

I don't know how does your viewmodel looks like so i have created one test viewmodel and interface.

```
 public interface IEntityViewModel<T>
{
    T Id { get; set; }
    DateTime Created { get; set; }
    DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

}

public class UrlRecViewModel : IEntityViewModel<Int64>
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this did not work. however, you have given me some ideas to explore. thank you